# I Cannot deploy my WCF service on IIS using WSHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, deployment

I really need help here. 
I'm trying to deploy a .NET WCF Application I have been working on for the past month for the first time.

I'm using IIS 7 as my WCF host, and working with wsHTTPBinding because I need to use Session object to store credentials. My client is a WPF App that use MVVM pattern with Caliburn.Micro.

So far, I manage (I think) to succesfully create the service on IIS. 
If I browse **"http://localhost/Ohmio/OhmioService.svc"** i see the "You create a service" message. But when I run my client and try to connect to it, my App close with an error "the application has stoped working..." bla bla bla.

This is my server Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
    <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>    
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>    
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>    
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>      
        <binding name="myBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">         
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None" />
      <reliableSession enabled="true" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior" name="WcfService1.OhmioSVC">    
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBinding" contract="WcfService1.IOhmioSVC" >          
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">          
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And this is the Client App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IOhmioSVC" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"/>
        <security mode="None" />
            <reliableSession enabled="true" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/Ohmio/OhmioService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IOhmioSVC" contract="OhmioSVC.IOhmioSVC" name="WSHttpBinding_IOhmioSVC">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Of couse my application works fine on my develope machine.
Please Help! I don't even know where to start looking for the cause.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Ok. I put the Try catch as suggested and the error goes:

> Exception: Cannot open secure cannel due to security negotiation with remote endpoint.

The inner exception:

> This endpoint do not admit the action ... and only proccess WSReliableMessaging

Comment: You need to do a try/catch around where your client tries to connect to the service, then include the exception information, including any inner exceptions, in your question.

Comment: Thanks! see my update please!

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146189/wcf-service-securitynegotiationexception

Comment: Yes. Found it right after edit the post. Remove the <security mode="None" /> from server Web.config. Now I get only the error about WSReliableMessaging.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a duplicate of this one:

[How to configure WCF Service with wsHttpBinding hosted on IIS and consumable over Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161966/how-to-configure-wcf-service-with-wshttpbinding-hosted-on-iis-and-consumable-ove)

But I do not have the reputation to mark it as such.

Comment: Thanks for the sugest. Already try what the other answer sugest. I don't think is the same problem. The post you mention it's about connecting to the web server from outside the network. I didn't get there! I'm only trying to run server and client in the same machine!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is something to do with reliable sessions (not 100% sure but my nerve is telling me). I found some article that might help you with regards to the [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911221/what-is-the-purpose-of-wcf-reliable-session) of reliable session.

Hope this would helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is definitely ReliableSession, and the concept of "PerSession". I get rid of the error, but when i call two methods of my web service, previous values from variables are lost. I think that IIS does not recognize that the two service calls are made from same client

Comment: The only idea that cross my mind is re-write my code to créate myself the sessions. That is, when a client call "Login" method, server creates a SessionID or AccesTicket, save it on a database and return it to client. On the next method call, the client need to specify a valid SessionID that server validate against database. If valid returns the data, else throw and exception.